# Price only shows up as $0.00

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make a menu that calculates the total cost at the end, however the end cost is supposed to show up in the text box but it only shows $0.00 can anyone help. It is supposed to display as a total cost for your choice of main dish as well as how many sides and/or toppings the customer would choose.See code attached.

```
Public Class frmMenu
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        'Set variables
        Dim decCBurger As Decimal = 11D
        Dim decChicken As Decimal = 7.49D
        Dim decFries As Decimal = 5.99D
        Dim decOnionRings As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decSalad As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decSoup As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decFP As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decPickle As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decOnion As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decTomato As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decBacon As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decEgg As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
        Dim decSides As Decimal
        Dim decTop As Decimal
        Dim decMain As Decimal

        'Display cost and label 
        txtTotalCost.Text = decTotalCost.ToString("C")
        decTotalCost = decTop + decSides + decMain

        ' Check for main dish
        If radCBurger.Checked Then
            decMain = decCBurger
        ElseIf radChicken.Checked Then
            decMain = decChicken
        End If
        'Check for side dishes
        If chkFries.Checked Then
            decSides = decFries
        End If
        If chkOnionRings.Checked Then
            decSides = decOnionRings
        End If
        If chkFP.Checked Then
            decSides = decFP
        End If
        If chkSoup.Checked Then
            decSides = decSoup
        End If
        If chkSalad.Checked Then
            decSides = decSalad
        End If
        'Check for Toppings
        If chkOnion.Checked Then
            decTop = decOnion
        End If
        If chkTomato.Checked Then
            decTop = decTomato
        End If
        If chkBacon.Checked Then
            decTop = decBacon
        End If
        If chkEgg.Checked Then
            decTop = decEgg
        End If
        If chkPickle.Checked Then
            decTop = decPickle
        End If
```

Comment: Why do people tag things as VBA when the code is obviously not VBA?!?

Comment: It looks to me like you're displaying your values before you've even assigned them.

Comment: the 'Display cost and label ' should be at the end. a computer program commands executed in the order they are written.

Comment: Plus, your decMain assignments should probably be `decmain = decmain + decCBurger`. And the counters should probably be of an Integer type instead of a decimal, unless you expect to sell partial sides.

Answer (score 1):

This should be at the end of your sub and you reversed the lines. You cannot expect the computer to know what you want. You are calculating at the begining so your total will always be 0.00.

```
 'Display cost and label 
        decTotalCost = decTop + decSides + decMain
        txtTotalCost.Text = decTotalCost.ToString("C")
```

so like this

```
Public Class frmMenu
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        'Set variables
        Dim decCBurger As Decimal = 11D
        Dim decChicken As Decimal = 7.49D
        Dim decFries As Decimal = 5.99D
        Dim decOnionRings As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decSalad As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decSoup As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decFP As Decimal = 5.99
        Dim decPickle As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decOnion As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decTomato As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decBacon As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decEgg As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
        Dim decSides As Decimal
        Dim decTop As Decimal
        Dim decMain As Decimal

        ' Check for main dish
        If radCBurger.Checked Then
            decMain = decCBurger
        ElseIf radChicken.Checked Then
            decMain = decChicken
        End If
        'Check for side dishes
        If chkFries.Checked Then
            decSides = decFries
        End If
        If chkOnionRings.Checked Then
            decSides = decOnionRings
        End If
        If chkFP.Checked Then
            decSides = decFP
        End If
        If chkSoup.Checked Then
            decSides = decSoup
        End If
        If chkSalad.Checked Then
            decSides = decSalad
        End If
        'Check for Toppings
        If chkOnion.Checked Then
            decTop = decOnion
        End If
        If chkTomato.Checked Then
            decTop = decTomato
        End If
        If chkBacon.Checked Then
            decTop = decBacon
        End If
        If chkEgg.Checked Then
            decTop = decEgg
        End If
        If chkPickle.Checked Then
            decTop = decPickle
        End If


        'Display cost and label 
        decTotalCost = decTop + decSides + decMain
        txtTotalCost.Text = decTotalCost.ToString("C")


end sub

end class
```

Comment: This is still wrong. Suppose the user checks every box. Only the last Side or Topping will be added at the end . Try a += This is equivalent to decTop = decTop +decTomato